# Keyboard hook error

Tags: vb.net

I am having some trouble getting some code to work. Here it is:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class KeyboardHook

    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Overloads Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal HookProc As KBDLLHookProc, ByVal hInstance As IntPtr, ByVal wParam As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Overloads Shared Function CallNextHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Overloads Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
        Public vkCode As UInt32
        Public scanCode As UInt32
        Public flags As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags
        Public time As UInt32
        Public dwExtraInfo As UIntPtr
    End Structure

    <Flags()> _
    Private Enum KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags As UInt32
        LLKHF_EXTENDED = &H1
        LLKHF_INJECTED = &H10
        LLKHF_ALTDOWN = &H20
        LLKHF_UP = &H80
    End Enum

    Public Shared Event KeyDown(ByVal Key As Keys)
    Public Shared Event KeyUp(ByVal Key As Keys)

    Private Const WH_KEYBOARD_LL As Integer = 13
    Private Const HC_ACTION As Integer = 0
    Private Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
    Private Const WM_KEYUP = &H101
    Private Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN = &H104
    Private Const WM_SYSKEYUP = &H105

    Private Delegate Function KBDLLHookProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

    Private KBDLLHookProcDelegate As KBDLLHookProc = New KBDLLHookProc(AddressOf KeyboardProc)
    Private HHookID As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    Private WithEvents kbHook As New KeyboardHook


    Private Function KeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
        If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
            Dim struct As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
            Select Case wParam
                Case WM_KEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYDOWN
                    RaiseEvent KeyDown(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
                Case WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYUP
                    RaiseEvent KeyUp(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
            End Select
        End If
        Return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        HHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KBDLLHookProcDelegate, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32, 0)
        If HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
            Throw New Exception("Could not set keyboard hook")
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        If Not HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(HHookID)
        End If
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub

    Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown
        Debug.WriteLine(Key.ToString)
    End Sub
    Private Sub kbHook_KeyUp(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyUp
        Debug.WriteLine(Key)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I have set: Project -> [Project Name] Properties -> Debug -> Uncheck “Enable the Visual Studio hosting process”

I get the following error:

```
System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

Can I please have some help on this situation?

thanks

Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Private WithEvents kbHook As New KeyboardHook
```

Your KeyboardHook constructor initializes the members of the class, including kbHook.  Which, due to the As New keyword constructs a new instance of KeyboardHook.  Which initializes the members of the class, including kbHook.  Which, ... *Kaboom!*

Remove kbHook and put it somewhere else, like in a form.

Note that your code can't work on a 64-bit operating system with AnyCPU in effect, the Marshal.GetHINSTANCE() cast is broken.  Ask another question about it if you need help.

Comment: Remove kbHook from that class.